# Does Caustic's gas affect teammates?

Tags: apex-legends

Do Caustic's gas traps or ultimate gas grenade affect my teammate movement speed or do damage?

[image: Nox gas]

I haven't heard my teammates complain about it. Also I can't test it with my friends because they don't have the game.

Comment: Does anything else affect teammates? Why are you asking about this specifically?

Comment: I like to play with Caustic only, it would be useful if you can contribute with anything else that affect teammates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The gas trap definitly affects team mates movement speed, though not in a good way**

As far as I can tell, it does not deal damage. I actually doubt that friendly fire is in any way possible (maybe through Bangalore & Gibraltar ultimate). It also reduces vision, just like Bangalore's smoke grenade.

As I don't own Caustic, I can't tell if a friendly Caustic is affected the same as any other friendly character. Also I am not certain about Caustic ultimate gas grenade, yet I would assume it to behave the same way

---

This is all based on my own experience within the game.

Comment: I believe the ultimate gas grenade affects them too? I have never tried to get hit by friendly bombing run from Bangalore or Gibraltar

Comment: I don't remember if I have ever been affected by the ultimate gas grenade. Yet you could be right that Bangalore/Gibraltar ultimates deal friendly fire

Comment: Fairly certain the ultimates for Bangalore and Gibraltar do not deal damage to teammates, but they do stun you or blur your vision as they do to enemies.

Answer (score 2):

Caustic main here, quick answer is : Nope, it doesn't, the only thing that affects is their visibility,even Bloodhound is affected in this one.

Answer (score 1):

It affects them the same way it affects enemies, except **without** doing damage. Same with his ultimate.

Answer (score -4):

Exactly right it has all of the same effects on teammates as it doesn't enemies except for dealing damage. I don't know why they made it like this because it makes him unplayable. If you are on my team playing him and you get down in an area where your gas is I am not reviving you.